# Não consigo validar a extensão da imagem usando o charAt

Tags: javascript, html, if, chart

Estou tentando fazer uma validação simples na extensão das imagens que vão ocorrer o upload, porém não está dando muito certo até o momento, poderiam me ajudar?

Segue o código que estou tentando fazer funcionar.

```
var aoptionFoto = document.getElementById("optionsFotoImg").value;
var aopcDemaisTemFoto = ['Sim', 'Não'];
var ainput13 = document.getElementById("OutroTipoImagemFile").value == "";
var validaExt = ['jpg', 'png','gif', 'jpeg'];
var extImagem = ainput13.charAt(ainput13.length-3);

if(aoptionFoto == 'Sim' && ainput13 == true){
      swal({
        title: "Ops.. Algo está errado !",
        text: "Para finalizar a compra é necessario fazer o upload da imagem.",
        button: "Continuar",
      });
      document.formMonteCaixa.OutroTipoImagemFile[0].focus();

    }else if(aoptionFoto == 'Sim' && ainput13 == false && extImagem != validaExt){
      swal({
        title: "Ops.. Algo está errado !",
        text: "Para finalizar a compra é necessario fazer o upload da imagem com extensões valida.",
        button: "Continuar",
      });
      document.formMonteCaixa.OutroTipoImagemFile[0].focus();

  }else{
    document.getElementById('BlocoDeEnvioEmailPag').style.display = 'block';
  }

<p>Faça o upload da imagem</p>
            <input name="OutroTipoImagemFile" id="OutroTipoImagemFile" accept="image/*" type="file">
```

O erro que retorna no console é esse:

Uncaught TypeError: ainput13.charAt is not a function
    at FinalizarCompra ((index):407)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):753)

Comment: Tem erro no código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está comparando valores errados. O `charAt` também está pegando apenas 1 caractere na string. Faça o seguinte, use `split` e `.pop()` para pegar a extensão (o `split` quebra o nome do arquivo em array e o `pop()` pega o valor do último index da array, que é justamente a extensão):

```
var ainput = document.getElementById("OutroTipoImagemFile").value;
var ainput13 = ainput == "";
var validaExt = ['jpg', 'png','gif', 'jpeg'];
var extImagem = ainput.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
```

E aqui:

```
}else if(aoptionFoto == 'Sim' && ainput13 == false && extImagem != validaExt){
```

Você altera para:

```
}else if(aoptionFoto == 'Sim' && ainput13 == false && !~validaExt.indexOf(extImagem)){
```

Para verificar se a extensão existe na array.

**Código completo:**

```
var aoptionFoto = document.getElementById("optionsFotoImg").value;
var aopcDemaisTemFoto = ['Sim', 'Não'];
var ainput = document.getElementById("OutroTipoImagemFile").value;
var ainput13 = ainput == "";
var validaExt = ['jpg', 'png','gif', 'jpeg'];
var extImagem = ainput.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

if(aoptionFoto == 'Sim' && ainput13 == true){
      swal({
        title: "Ops.. Algo está errado !",
        text: "Para finalizar a compra é necessario fazer o upload da imagem.",
        button: "Continuar",
      });
      document.formMonteCaixa.OutroTipoImagemFile[0].focus();

    }else if(aoptionFoto == 'Sim' && ainput13 == false && !~validaExt.indexOf(extImagem)){
      swal({
        title: "Ops.. Algo está errado !",
        text: "Para finalizar a compra é necessario fazer o upload da imagem com extensões valida.",
        button: "Continuar",
      });
      document.formMonteCaixa.OutroTipoImagemFile[0].focus();

  }else{
    document.getElementById('BlocoDeEnvioEmailPag').style.display = 'block';
  }

<p>Faça o upload da imagem</p>
            <input name="OutroTipoImagemFile" id="OutroTipoImagemFile" accept="image/*" type="file">
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado !

Comment: Corrigi o código porque não estava reconhecendo a extensão jpeg por ter 4 caracteres.